# Apache default root doesn't change for my domain in linux server

Tags: linux, apache, dns, centos7

I know in Apache, there are virtual hosts. When a request is given, it goes and search between these virtual hosts to see if there are server name like request. It takes its option back like document root and others I have this file in `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/example.com/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I defined all directories as well like `/var/www/example.com/html` and after all that, I have a file named `/etc/httpd/conf` at its last line I added this code:

```
Include sites-enabled/*.conf
```

After that when I restart httpd it performs complete with no errors, but it doesn't work and it goes to its default root. Where is the problem?

Comment: Does your included file extension is .conf ? Are you sure you access your server on 80 port ( standart http) ? Are your logfiles empty ? Are you sure you provide the good value to servername and serveralias ?

Comment: yes.my file is example.com.conf that my virtual host option is located there and for server name and server alias i am sure but for port  80 how can i know which port is in use?

Comment: Is there maybe an another .conf file that contains VirtualHost definition for the same ServerName/Alias?

Comment: no. i have just one .conf file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it just with replacing star with my local ip in linux in virtualhost tag

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
```

after too many examination it works finally.there was no problem in other places.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create a virtual host configuration file, in your example, `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`

You need to use the command as super user

```
a2ensite example.com
```

And then restart Apache:

```
systemctl reload apache2
```

You can tell what virtual hosts are up and running by the command:

```
apache2ctl -S
```

Comment: my system is centos so i have httpd but i search the equation of a2ensite in httpd and i found sites-enabled and site-available and so i make these folders and link them with ln -s but it goes to default root again .what do u guess to be problem be there?

Comment: Does this help? https://serverfault.com/questions/472954/a2ensite-equivalent-in-centos

Comment: yes.exactly i use this link as guide before your comment .that is helpful but doesn't solve my problem.:                                                                                           
    //listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };//listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };                                         these tow lines are located in my named.conf in etc folder.do u see any problem?